# Integral $E_n(a_1,...,a_n;t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2\cos(tx)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x^2+a_k^2)}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

> Evaluate 
>   $$E_n(a_1,...,a_n;t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2\cos(tx)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x^2+a_k^2)}dx$$
>   for $i\ne j\iff a_i^2\ne a_j^2$, and $a_i\in\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$.

I've been able to find the similar integral
$$J_n(a_1,...,a_n;t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(tx)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x^2+a_k^2)}dx$$
by seeing that we can write 
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{z+\alpha_k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{z+\alpha_k}\prod_{k\ne j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\alpha_j-\alpha_k}\ ,$$
And then using $z\equiv x^2$, $\alpha_k\equiv a_k^2$ to get 
$$J_n(a_1,...,a_n;t)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}J_1(a_k;t)\prod_{k\ne j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_j^2-a_k^2}\ .$$
Then we take the Laplace transform of the remaining integral:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{J_1(q;t)\}(s)&=2\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(tx)}{x^2+q^2}dxdt\\
&=2\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+q^2}\int_0^\infty \cos(tx)e^{-st}dtdx\\
&=2\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+q^2}\text{Re }\int_0^\infty e^{-(s-ix)t}dtdx\\
&=2\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+q^2}\text{Re }\left[\frac1{s-ix}\right]dx\\
&=2s\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(x^2+q^2)(x^2+s^2)}dx\\
&=\frac{2s}{s^2-q^2}\left[\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2+q^2}-\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2+s^2} \right]\\
&=\frac{\pi s}{s^2-q^2}\left[\frac{1}q-\frac{1}s \right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{q}\left[\mathcal{L}\{\cosh(qt)\}(s)-\mathcal{L}\{\sinh(qt)\}(s)\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{q}\mathcal{L}\{e^{-qt}\}(s)\ .
\end{align}$$
Which gives $$J_1(q;t)=\frac{\pi}{q}e^{-qt}$$
and $$J_n(a_1,...,a_n;t)=\pi\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{e^{-a_k t}}{a_k}\prod_{k\ne j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_j^2-a_k^2}\ ,$$
from which many remarkable results may be derived.

I have the suspicion however, that we may be able to find $E_n$ in a similar way, but I don't know how. One idea:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(x^2+1)\cos(tx)}{(x^2+1)(x^2+\mathbf{a}_n^2)}dx=J_n(\mathbf{a}_n;t)=E_{n+1}(1,\mathbf{a}_n;t)+J_{n+1}(1,\mathbf{a}_n;t)$$
Where we used the shorthand notation $$x^2+\mathbf{a}_n^2\equiv\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x^2+a_k^2)$$
$$\mathbf{a}_n\equiv(a_k)_{k=1,...,n}\ .$$
It should be noted that the above holds for $1\not\in \mathbf{a}_n$.

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I see you've been busy generalizing that other integral!

Comment: @dxdydz I just can't help myself :)

Comment: $x^2=(x^2+a_1^2)-a_1^2$ in the numerator?..

Comment: (Yet another idea is to look at $\partial^2 J_n/\partial t^2$.)

Comment: Take the second derevative with respect to t

Comment: @metamorphy  I took your advice: $$E_ n[a_{k=1,...,n};t]=J_{n-1}[a_{j\ne k=1,...,n};t]-a_j^2J_n[a_{k=1,...,n};t]$$ for any $j=1,...,n$.

Comment: As long as $n > 1$, the degree of numerator in $\frac{z}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(z+\alpha_k)}$ is lower than that in denominator. For distinct $\alpha_k$, you have partial fraction decomposition: $$\frac{z}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}(z+\alpha_k)}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\color{red}{-\alpha_k}}{z+\alpha_k}\prod\limits_{k\ne j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\alpha_j-\alpha_k}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe I've overlooked this for so long.

Let $$u(x,t)=\frac{\cos(tx)}{\prod_{k=\color{red}{2}}^{n}(x^2+a_n^2)}.$$

We may write
$$E_n(a_1,...,a_n;t)=\int_\Bbb R \frac{x^2+a_1^2-a_1^2}{x^2+a_1^2}u(x,t)dx=\int_\Bbb Ru(x,t)dx-a_1^2\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{u(x,t)dx}{x^2+a_1^2},$$
which is
$$E_n(a_1,...,a_n;t)=J_{n-1}(a_2,...,a_n;t)-a_1^2J_n(a_1,...,a_n;t).$$

Answer (score 3):

Using Cauchy's residue theorem the computation is almost immediate. We can assume that all $a_k$ are positive. Then we have
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{x^2\cos(tx)}{\prod_k(x^2+a_k^2)}\,dx
&=\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{x^2e^{itx}}{\prod_k(x^2+a_k^2)}\,dx
\\&=2\pi i\sum_k\lim_{x\to ia_k}(x-ia_k)
\frac{x^2e^{itx}}{\prod_k(x^2+a_k^2)}
\\&=-\pi\sum_ke^{-ta_k}a_k\sum_{j\neq k}\frac1{a_j^2-a_k^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: This works! thanks :)

Comment: Quick clarification: your contour is the real line?

Comment: @clathratus You should first take the semicircle contour (see the first picture here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContourIntegration.html), and then take the limit $R\to\infty$. The integral over the arc vanishes in the limit, and thus the integral over the semicircle tends to the integral over the real line as $R\to\infty$.

Comment: Aah. I see. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have just to take the second derevative with respect to t to find $E$ in fonction of $J$.