# Clarification about proof involving product/sum manipulation

Tags: summation, products

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249765/integral-e-na-1-a-nt-int-infty-infty-fracx2-costx-prod-k?rq=1), the following simplification was made:
$$2\pi i\sum_k\lim_{x\to ia_k}(x-ia_k)
\frac{x^2e^{itx}}{\prod_j(x^2+a_j^2)}\\
=-\pi\sum_ke^{-ta_k}a_k\sum_{j\neq k}\frac1{a_j^2-a_k^2}.$$

What I have done is the following, but am unsure why it is wrong:
$$
2\pi i\sum_k\lim_{x\to ia_k}(x-ia_k)
\frac{x^2e^{itx}}{\prod_k(x^2+a_k^2)}\\
=2\pi i\sum_k \frac{(ia_k)^2e^{-ta_k}}{\prod_k (ia_k+ia_k)}.
$$
Even after reduction it does not matched the stated closed form. Where does the $\sum_{i\neq j}$ come from? I am unfamiliar with this notation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given $k$, the $k$-th inner term of the sum is (before taking the limit)
$$\begin{split}
(x-ia_k)\frac{x^2e^{itx}}{\prod_j(x^2+a_j^2)} &= \frac {(x - ia_k)}{x^2+a_k^2}
\cdot\frac{x^2e^{itx}}{\prod_{j \neq k}(x^2 + a_j^2)}\\
&=\frac {1}{x+ia_k}\cdot\frac{x^2e^{itx}}{\prod_{j\neq k}(x^2+a_j^2)}\\
\end{split}$$
where we used the fact that $x^2+a_k^2=(x-ia_k)(x+ia_k)$.

This implies
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow ia_k}(x-ia_k)\frac{x^2e^{itx}}{\prod_j(x^2+a_j^2)}=-\frac 1 {2ia_k}\frac{a_k^2e^{-ta_k}}{\prod_{j\neq k}(a_j^2-a_k^2)}$$
which yields the final result.

Comment: Ahh alright. Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem! Happy Holidays!